# Last 7 day with Open Status

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a ticket system tracker excel sheet that I use every day.  I'm looking to get the number of tickets opened in the last 7 days.  Column G shows if the ticket is "Closed or Open"  Column C shows the date of submission of the ticket. I want to be able to verify ticket is open and then count how many are still open in the last 7 days.  I have it somewhat pieced together but not totally working.  Any help would be appreciated

```
=COUNTIFS(Main!G:G,"Open",Main!C:C,"<"&TODAY()+1,Main!C:C,">="&TODAY()-7)
```

Comment: Jason - what results are you seeing? "Not totally working" is "kinda sorta vague!".  Also, unless Excel has new functions related to time travel the second "IF" is unnecessary as none of the results should have future dates.

Comment: I get 0 results.  There is something missing in my formula

Comment: There is a good chance that your dates may be text that look like dates and not true dates.

Comment: I have checked that.. Looking at the Cell Format of the column it's actually selected as dates in the format of 11/19/21 type

Comment: Well, you tagged "Excel-2010" and "Excel-2007". Which version are you on? On the mentioned versions you could use `=SUMPRODUCT((Main!G:G="Open")*(Main!C:C<TODAY()+1)*(Main!C:C>=&TODAY()-7))`.

Comment: Jason: based on the responses, I think the issue is that you are using the formula like a SUMIFS which has a criteria parameter.  SUMPRODUCT() covers the whole range of a column.  Use of criteria would be as @OverflowStacker noted.

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` isn't optimized for use with full columns. So you should refrain from using it to much or by limiting the ranges.

Comment: @JasonLucas - can you post a sample table of your data?  Maybe that will give us a better idea of what's not working?

Comment: @JasonLucas Checking the Cell format of the column does not inform as to whether the data stored in that column are "real" dates or text strings that look like dates.  "Real" dates will be numeric.  Format the column as General and observe if the displayed values change to integers (usually in the 40,000+range). Excel stores Dates as serial numbers with `1=1 Jan 1900`.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT((Main!G:G="Open")*(Main!C:C<TODAY()+1)*(Main!C:C>=&TODAY()-7))`